# Seeking shapefile of administrative divisions of Cote d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast) post-2011

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, africa

I've been trying to find a shapefile containing CIV's administrative divisions (preferably down to the level of sous-prefecture) reflecting the national reorganization of 2011 but have had no luck. Everything I've found thus far contains pre-2011 boundaries; does anyone know where I might find a shapefile representative of 2011 boundaries?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this website: http://gadm.org/country

Here you can select 'Côte d'Ivoire' and download the corresponding data in several formats. On the download page, you can already preview if this is what you actually looked for. Normally, the 'GADM database of Global Administrative Areas' is kept up-to-date and contains as many details as possible.

Comment: GADM is usually my first stop for administrative boundary shapefiles. Their boundaries have actually not been updated in several years, their current updates are addressing this but their CIV shapefile has several issues still.